# Jmeter didn't get the correct number of rows in my csv file

Tags: java, python, jmeter, bufferedreader, beanshell

I had this problem for some time now. I had a test plan that should loop base on the number of files on a folder, then it will again loop base on the number of rows inside the file. Both are working now, the problem is the second file loops the same number as the first file if the rows of the first is greater than the second.

example 1.

```
file1.csv --> 10 rows
file2.csv --> 5 rows
```

file1.csv will loop 10 times, file2.csv will also loop 10 times (should only loop 5).

Another scenario is this:

example 2.

```
file1.csv --> 5 rows
file2.csv --> 10 rows
```

file1.csv will loop 10 times, file2.csv will loop 10 times.

Can anyone explain why is this happening and is there a way to fix this.

Below is the screenshot of my test plan. Thanks

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Would be asked too much to post the code in a code block instead of an image?

Comment: BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( vars.get("testPath") + vars.get("current_file")));
int counter = 0;  


for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
 if(counter == 0){
  
  vars.put("headers",line);
  
 }else{
  
  vars.put("testCase_" + counter, line);
  
 }
}
reader.close();

Here's the code.

Comment: Hmm, that's a comment and not a code block ;) - you know you can [edit] your question, don't you? Just pasting code into a comment isn't suited to enable people to like it more or be of more help since it is poorly formatted, scattered in comments and thus way harder to read.

Comment: @albertJ do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

> Both are working now, the problem is the second file loops the same number as >the first file if the rows of the first is greater than the second.
>
> file1.csv --> 10 rows
>
> file2.csv --> 5 rows

Assuming that you use testCase_N variable in your **ForEach Controller**:

Your script will create variables testCase_1 .. testCase_10 (with vars.put()  call) on **iteration 1**.

On **iteration 2** it will call vars.put() to create variables testCase_1 .. testCase_5.

Variables testCase_6 .. testCase_10 still exist after **iteration 1** and will be used in the inner loop.

You can call [remove()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#remove(java.lang.String)) method to delete the remaining variables.

Comment: Do you have an idea on where to put the remove() method? I tried to insert it inside the for loop, but it only limit the loop to just one. Here's my code:         
for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
 if(counter == 0){
  
  vars.put("headers", line);
  
 }else{
  
  vars.put("testCase_" + counter, line);
  
 }
 remove("testCase_" + counter);
 counter++;
}
reader.close();

Comment: @albertJ you could try to call `clear()` before adding new entries, i.e. remove everything at the start of your code snippet.

Comment: You are deleting the variables just after adding them. Add another loop to `remove()` the obsolete variables before adding the new ones. Don't forget about the special case when you don't have any variables added on  loop iteration 1.